# How to sort two arraylist and then compare that they are same

Tags: c#

> I am trying to sort the two array elements and match them with one another if one any one match it returns lucky otherwise unlucky, any ideas that where i am going to wrong

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Apptest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr1 = { 5,4,3,8,1};
        int[] arr2 = { 8,1,5,4,3};
        string str = rollingdice(arr1, arr2);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
    public static string rollingdice(int[] input1, int[] input2)
    {
       // input1.Sort();
        //input2.Sort();
        for(int i=0;i<input1.Length && i<input2.Length;i++)
        {
            if (!Object.Equals(input1[i], input2[i]))
            {
                return "unlucky";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Lucky";
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you have any ideas where you are going wrong? An error message, unexpected behaviour, etc.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements too. Does every element have to match between both arrays or does just one element have to match? I read ` if one any one match it returns lucky otherwise unlucky` as meaning just one has to match. I'm guessing English isn't your first language so this isn't a criticism, just a request for clarification. Perhaps some examples of what is lucky and what isn't. eg if the arrays where `{1,2,3}` and `{1,2,4}` is that lucky or not? And how about `{1,1,2}` and `{1,2,2}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Array.Sort<int>(input1);
Array.Sort<int>(input2);
bool equal = input1.SequenceEqual(input2);
return equal ? "lucky" : "unlucky";  // lucky in your sample
```

Comment: Do not forgot the `:` between `lucky` and `unlucky`

Comment: Simple and elegant. Nice.

Comment: but i have to make manipulation inside rollingdice() only so what code should be there please do you have any idea

Comment: Hmm... I read " if one any one match it returns lucky otherwise unlucky" as meaning only one has to match. Time to request clarification I think. :)

Comment: @user3417203: What makes you think that the above code couldn't go in the `rollingdice` method?

Comment: @user3417203 You can use `Array.Sort(input1)`.

Comment: @user3417203: I would guess that Tim assumed since you had those lines commented out in the code that they were valid methods to sort that you had temporarily taken out.

Comment: @user3417203: sorry, fixed that. Now i'm using `Array.Sort` (i should remove these confusing extensions in my test-project).

Comment: Of course the type parameter `<int>` (to the method) can be omitted as it is easily inferred by the compiler.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: You're right.  I wasn't sure if there is a difference to the generic version (acc. to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4(v=vs.110).aspx) it's the same). However, i would still prefer to add `int` because it's short and clear and i don't need to remember that the compiler is able to infer the type in the non-generic version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the result of the sorted array

```
var foo = input1.Sort();
var bar = input2.Sort();
```

Then compare foo and bar.

Comment: The `Sort` method on arrays is not an instance method (it is `static`). Also, that methods sorts "in place" (unlike e.g. Linq's `OrderBy`), so no, you do not assign the result (the `void` return type cannot be assigned to a variable).

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to check for equality in this case would be:

```
bool equal = arr1.Length == arr2.Length && !arr1.Except(arr2).Any();
```

Comment: That might not necessarily work if there are duplicates in the arrays. ie should (1,1,2) be considered a match for (1,2,2). The question is very unclear on what the requirements actually are.

Comment: Whoops, `Enumerable.Except` returns the set difference between both, not an `int`. But even if you fix it it's not a viable approach. `Enumerable.Except` uses a set which removes duplicates. So `1,1` would be the same as `1`. You are also checking only one side, so if all of `arr1` are in `arr2` but not the opposite.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Whoops, my bad!

Comment: @Chris Edited, taking that into account now too.